# What is the mathematical principle behind Intra-Prediction and Motion Estimation?

Tags: h.264, codec, encoder, hevc, openh264

For the generation of encoders I have seen that the Intra Modes have increased from 9 (in H264) to 66 (in VVC + wide aange modes). I want to know the mathematics/mathematical principle for the block predicted using Intra-prediction. The Motion estimation in H264 was based on 1/4 pel and now in VVC it is 1/16 pel. I wonder the mathematics behind this.
Can someone give a clear idea regarding this. I would be really thankful for that.

Comment: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=H264

Comment: @Soleil the above papers doesn't describe the Mathematical principle. I can only see the mechanism that I already know and we can get it from google

Comment: You want to dig this paper: A fast hierarchical 1/4-pel fractional pixel motion estimation algorithm of H.264/AVC video coding; https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6566493